# How to boot from grub2 when installed without?

Tags: grub2

I have installed Ubuntu Desktop 18.10 from the terminal with “ubiquity -b” without the bootloader (bcs there were some problems with grub2) and then independently grub2. Now, grub2 is fully working, it shows the minimal BASH line on PC startup but how to boot the Ubuntu from it without any errors or problems?

Note: I have UEFI bios and cant change it.

Comment: First of all, how did you installed GRUB2? Is there an appropriate FAT32 efi-partition on a drive also and did GRUB2 installed in there?

Comment: I am not 100 % sure but the live CD installer probably installed a bit of the grub and then I reinstalled it fully with boot-repair.

Comment: I created 2 partitions before installing. EFI 500 MB and EXT4 about 25 GB.

Comment: I have tried practically all the tutorials etc. on Google and YouTube and several forums. Updated BIOS. Installed Windows 10 again and tried to install it alongside the Windows. Nothing has worked. Also disabled TPM in BIOS and set grubx64.efi as trusted.

Comment: Look, you don't need such a large space for EFI-partition. It is enough 33MB - a smallest possible FAT32 partition size for it. You can resize any partition using Gparted Live ISO. Just make an botable USB with it and resize it.

Comment: Then you need using any Live ISO enter an chroot mode to you installed system. In chroot mode you will need to reinstall grub and run update-grub command which should find all your installed OS's and create the appropriate boot menu for them in Grub2.

Comment: To perform chroot, first you need to find out how your parition table looks: on which partition what OS has been installed. Please, note here all your partitions.